# wcf dual channel error

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service that users can chat trough it.
when I test it in local IIS it works, but when publish it in external server, and call a method, it throws:

> Security negotiation failed because the remote party did not send back
>   a reply in a timely manner. This may be because the underlying
>   transport connection was aborted.

webconfig.conf

```
....

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="bind" textEncoding="utf-8">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>

      </wsDualHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="svcbh">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>

      <service name="QasedakServer.QasedakAPI" behaviorConfiguration="svcbh">

        <host>

          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://www.mywebsite.com/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="duplexendpoint" address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="QasedakServer.IQasedakAPI" bindingConfiguration="bind" />
        <endpoint name="MetaDataTcpEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

....
```

my program uses dual channel mode connection.
plz help me.

Comment: are your ports opened on the firewall?

Comment: which ports? I use a simple web-hosting service, so how can I know are  required ports opened?